# Post hundred of fields with ajax - post request

Tags: php, ajax

I have a really big form that can grow in size through the use of javascript (a user can replicate some parts of the form to add more data. A user had added something like 1000 fields in the form, passed to a php page that write an xml.

The problem is that some of the last fields of the form are not written in the xml, like there was a limit on 1000 elements...

The ajax call is:

```
var xmlform = document.getElementById("xmlForm");
var postData = $(xmlform).serializeArray();
var success = false;
var file = "";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_xml_download.php",
    data : postData,
    dataType: 'html',
    async : false,
    complete: function(html){
        file = html.responseText;
        success = true;
    }
});
$("#ajaxform").submit();

if (success){
    window.open("downloadxml.php?file=" + file + "&value=" + value);
}
```

The ajax call is always a success and through the developers tools in chrome I can see in the call to ajax_xml_download.php all the fields that are passed. But some of them are not written...

I print a count of the $_REQUEST array in the landing php page and there was 1011 elements... hope this can help...

downloadxml.php is a simple page that permits the download of the file.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do next. If there was a limit of 1000 field items, and you need to collect data from ore than 1000, you can make a loop. Collect data from 500 fields, serialize it, post it with a tag that alerts the PHP script that more data s coming, repeat until all the data is passed over.

Comment: Might also be a limit on the `POST` data. May want to check php.ini or `phpinfo()` to see what the POST max is set to.

Comment: @Twisty, the value `post_max_size` is 512M... I didn't set a limit to 1000 fields... but just a few elements aren't written by the destination page on the xml file

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution... there is a limit on POST value set in the php.ini

```
max_input_vars
```

that by default is 1000. I inserted the value in the php.ini (it wasn't present) and setted to 2000 and the form now is functioning.

Hope it help somebody...